# WHERE Clause vs ON when using JOIN

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2, inner-join

Assuming that I have the following T-SQL code:

```
SELECT * FROM Foo f
INNER JOIN Bar b ON b.BarId = f.BarId;
WHERE b.IsApproved = 1;
```

The following one also returns the same set of rows:

```
SELECT * FROM Foo f
INNER JOIN Bar b ON (b.IsApproved = 1) AND (b.BarId = f.BarId);
```

This might not be the best case sample here but is there any performance difference between these two?

Comment: Here's a similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2509987/which-sql-query-is-faster-filter-on-join-criteria-or-where-clause

Comment: The machine will figure it out and optimize it properly.  However, for the humans that will need to debug\modify\support your code years from now, keep the filtering conditions in the `WHERE` and join conditions in the `ON`.

Comment: @KM. I don't always know how to tell the difference between what's a join condition and a what's a filter. For example [in this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9303069/119477) I think its better in the join so is that a "Join condition" then? [Here's another example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6473403/119477) which I don't even know how to rewrite the equivalent where clause.

Comment: a join condition is: `tableA.column = tableB.column` a filter condition is `tableA.Column=5`.  When doing outer joins (LEFT/RIGHT) you must put the filter conditions within the `ON` or code your `WHERE` in this manner `(tableA.Column=5 OR tableA.Column IS NULL)`

Answer (score 35, accepted):

No, the query optimizer is smart enough to choose the same execution plan for both examples.

You can use `SHOWPLAN` to check the execution plan.

---

Nevertheless, you should put all join connection on the `ON` clause and all the restrictions on the `WHERE` clause.

Comment: Beat me to it.  Although as a matter of preference, I'd go with the JOIN as it's more descriptive.

Comment: Thanks! Imagine a situation with 7 or 8 INNER JOINS. Is your answer applicable to those situations as well?

Comment: @Ste IMO, it's actually more confusing to put everything in the `JOIN`. Use `JOIN` to relate to tables in a query. Use `WHERE` to filter results. It's when you mix the two and use **only** one or the other that queries become hard to read.

Comment: @Yuck.  Fair point and I would agree on the mix becoming unmanageable.

Comment: @Ste: I actually generally prefer the mix of JOIN and WHERE provided the purpose of each keyword is enforced in query writing. The JOIN clauses determine how tables are linked into a "wide" result set, and then the WHERE clause determines the filtering of said results. Given that, I feel it's easier to decipher a query with JOINs and a WHERE than it would be to decipher a query with only JOINs, just as it's easier to decipher JOINs than a query with only a WHERE clause defining both join and filter criteria.

Comment: @KeithS: I guess I've never really monitored my usage. I shall report back later and start off a chat about it.  :)

Answer (score 47):

Just be careful of the difference with outer joins. A query where a filter of `b.IsApproved` (on the right table, Bar) is added to the `ON` condition of the `JOIN`:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Foo f 
LEFT OUTER JOIN Bar b ON (b.IsApproved = 1) AND (b.BarId = f.BarId);
```

Is *NOT* the same as placing the filter in the `WHERE` clause:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Foo f 
LEFT OUTER JOIN Bar b ON (b.BarId = f.BarId)
WHERE (b.IsApproved = 1);
```

Since for 'failed' outer joins to `Bar` (i.e. where there is no `b.BarId` for a `f.BarId`), this will leave `b.IsApproved` as `NULL` for all such failed join rows, and these rows will then be filtered out.

Another way of looking at this is that for the first query, `LEFT OUTER JOIN Bar b ON (b.IsApproved = 1) AND (b.BarId = f.BarId)` will always return the LEFT table rows, since `LEFT OUTER JOIN` guarantees the LEFT table rows will be returned even if the join fails. However, the effect of adding `(b.IsApproved = 1)` to the `LEFT OUTER JOIN` on condition is to NULL out any right table columns when `(b.IsApproved = 1)` is false, i.e. as per the same rules normally applied to a `LEFT JOIN` condition on `(b.BarId = f.BarId)`.

**Update**:
To complete the question asked by Conrad, the equivalent LOJ for an OPTIONAL filter would be:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Foo f 
LEFT OUTER JOIN Bar b ON (b.BarId = f.BarId)
WHERE (b.IsApproved IS NULL OR b.IsApproved = 1);
```

i.e. The `WHERE` clause needs to consider both the condition whether the join fails `(NULL)` and the filter is to be ignored, and where the join succeeds and the filter must be applied. (`b.IsApproved` or `b.BarId` could be tested for `NULL`)

I've put a [SqlFiddle together here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/db4e0/2) which demonstrates the differences between the various placements of the `b.IsApproved` filter relative to the `JOIN`.

Comment: Very good point. If you put filter criteria testing data from an outer join into the outer join itself, you'll get more rows than you expect because all Foos will be returned regardless of the status or existence of Bar. When filtering is specified separately from joining, the rows from the two tables are first joined, and then the filter removes the entire row from the table where the criteria is not met.

Comment: @nonnb Ok but if you corrected the WHERE Clause on the 2nd query to `WHERE b.IsApproved = 1 or b.BarId is Null` it is the same. Now which one do you do?

Comment: @nonnn um you wouldn't need `OR (b.BarId IS NULL) ` in the left join version only in the WHERE version and you wanted to make it same.

Answer (score 6):

```
SELECT * FROM Foo f
INNER JOIN Bar b ON b.BarId = f.BarId
WHERE b.IsApproved = 1;
```

This is the better form to go. It is easy to read and easy to modify. In the business world this is what you would want to go with. As far as performance they are the same though.

Comment: In the my current situation, I favor the WHERE clause but couldn't avoid wondering if there is a perf diff. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I've seem some cases where the optimizer was not smart enough even on recent versions of MSSQL - and the performance difference was monster.

But this is a exception, most of time SQL Server optimizer will solve the problem and get the right plan.

So mantain the policy of using filters on WHERE clause and optimize when needed.

Answer (score 0):

I just ran a test of a query against four tables - one primary table with three INNER JOINs and a total of four paramters, and compared the execution plans of both approaches (using the filter criteria in the ON of the JOIN, and then also in the WHERE clause).

The execution plans are exactly the same.  I ran this on SQL Server 2008 R2.