# What is the difference when adding a filter criteria to an outer join instead of a where clause?

Tags: sql-server, join, filter, outer-join

I'm trying to filter out a table using filter in the outer join clause rather than a where clause.  When i try to do so i'm getting unexpected results.  The whole table is returned as though i didn't apply the filter at all.

When I run this example, i get different results for the last two queries.  I would expect them to have the same results but it's not the case.  What is going on here?

```
declare @a table
(
    id int
    ,content varchar(100)
)
declare @b table
(
    id int
    ,content varchar(100)
)

insert into @a (id,content) values (1,'Apple')
insert into @a (id,content) values (2,'Banana')
insert into @a (id,content) values (3,'Orange')
insert into @b (id,content) values (1,'Juice')
insert into @b (id,content) values (2,'Peel')
insert into @b (id,content) values (3,'Julius')

--basic outer join
select * from @a a left join @b b on a.id=b.id

--outer join with where clause filter
select * from @a a left join @b b on a.id=b.id where a.id=1

--outer join with join clause filter
select * from @a a left join @b b on a.id=1 and a.id=b.id
```

Comment: Have a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10297231/where-clause-vs-on-when-using-join/10297312#10297312

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An outer join is allowed to return NULL for the joined table's row, whereas a where clause must be matched before the result is returned.

```
select * from @a a left join @b b on a.id=b.id where a.id=1
```

translates to "Give me all rows from `a` where `id=1` and try to correlate this with any rows in `b` where `a.id=b.id`.

```
select * from @a a left join @b b on a.id=1 and a.id=b.id
```

on the other hand, translates to "Give me all rows from `a` and, if `a.id=1`, try to correlate this with any rows in `b`  where `a.id=b.id` (otherwise just give me the data from `a`).

Contrast this with an inner join, where adding a condition to the `ON` clause and adding it to the `WHERE` clause is synonymous.

Comment: so if i understand this right, the filter in the join clause is limiting the result set from one of the tables but not both.  whereas the where clause filters both.