# Difference between "on .. and" and "on .. where" in SQL Left Join?

Tags: sql, join, syntax, where-clause

Sql statement.

```
1.select a.* from A a left join B b on a.id =b.id and a.id=2;

2.select a.* from A a left join B b on a.id =b.id where a.id=2;
```

what is the difference of this two sql statement?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10297231/where-clause-vs-on-when-using-join

Comment: Not a duplicate, having `LEFT JOIN` here significantly changes the question.

Comment: @hvd - the questions may not be exact duplicates, but since most of the answers are along the lines of "it doesn't matter for `INNER JOIN`, but here's what would be different for `OUTER JOIN`s..."

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever is right, this question is duplicated from other questions that have already been accurately answered

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Closing as a duplicate is what you should do when the *question* is a duplicate, not when an answer to a different question happens to also answer this one. See [the FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#close): **exact duplicate** This question covers exactly the same content as earlier questions on this topic

Answer (score 45, accepted):

```
create table A(id int);
create table B(id int);

INSERT INTO A VALUES(1);
INSERT INTO A VALUES(2);
INSERT INTO A VALUES(3);

INSERT INTO B VALUES(1);
INSERT INTO B VALUES(2);
INSERT INTO B VALUES(3);

SELECT * FROM A;
SELECT * FROM B;

id
-----------
1
2
3

id
-----------
1
2
3
```

Filter on the JOIN to prevent rows from being added during the JOIN process.

```
select a.*,b.*
from   A a left join B b 
on     a.id =b.id and a.id=2;

id          id
----------- -----------
1           NULL
2           2
3           NULL
```

WHERE will filter after the JOIN has occurred.

```
select a.*,b.* 
from   A a left join B b 
on     a.id =b.id 
where  a.id=2;

id          id
----------- -----------
2           2
```

Comment: For some reason it didn't work as expected in this sqlfiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9684d/4
But when I tried it in MySQL it worked exactly as you said.

Comment: Would it be correct to say that adding ' and a.id=2' does not bring any difference to query and makes no sense? So we can safely just skip it and use LEFT JOIN

Comment: another application of where condition is to find unmatching data of LEFT table in RIGHT table using 'Where righttable.Id is NULL'

Answer (score 14):

```
select a.* from A a left join B b on a.id =b.id and a.id=2;
```

This only uses `a.id` in the join condition, so records where `a.id <> 2` don't get filtered out. You might get a result like this:

```
+------+------+
| a.id | b.id |
+------+------+
| 1    | NULL |
| 2    | 2    |
| 3    | NULL |
+------+------+
```

You don't select any of `b`'s columns, but if you do, it'll be easier to understand.

```
select a.* from A a left join B b on a.id =b.id where a.id=2;
```

Now records where `a.id <> 2` do get filtered out.

```
+------+------+
| a.id | b.id |
+------+------+
| 2    | 2    |
+------+------+
```

Comment: Is select a.* from A a left join B b on a.id =b.id and a.id=2;
equivalent to 
select a.* from A a left join B b on a.id =b.id ?

Comment: @Andrey No, even though no columns from `b` are selected, a successful join can cause `a`'s records to be duplicated in the result set.

Answer (score 0):

As [@hvd](https://stackoverflow.com/users/743382/hvd) says, the "where" clause filters rows returned by the join, so the "where" version won't return outer-joined rows (which have a.id = null).

However there is another significant difference: Even if the outer joined rows were not filtered out, there can be a massive performance boost putting the condition into the "on" clause, because the result set is made smaller earlier.

This is particularly pronounced when a series of other left joined tables follows the one with the "and" condition - you can prevent joins from even happening to the following tables for unsuitable rows and potentially chop off millions of rows from reaching the filtering ("where") stage.

Answer (score 0):

I try some time ,and I know what is the reason, it only related to a priority.

```
select * from A a left join B b on a.id=b.id and b.id=2
```

this means A left join (where b.id=2) this is the condition
 filter B first

```
Select *　from A a left join B b on a.id=b.id where a.id=2
```

this means after join B ,then filter by a.id=2

Answer (score 0):

If you think about the syntax of a SQL query, the 'AND' extends the join block (as if where parenthesis) where as the 'WHERE' defines the start of the WHERE/filtering block of the query.

Answer (score 0):

As clearly explained by the @mr_eclair

what happens in both cases.
Let me tell you an easy way to remember this.

```
select a.*,b.*
from   A a left join B b 
**on**     a.id =b.id ***and*** a.id=2;
```

Here the "AND" worked on the "ON" and it provides a condition to the joining criteria.

```
select a.*,b.* 
from   A a left join B b 
on     a.id =b.id 
**where**  a.id=2;
```

whereas here "WHERE" provided a condition to all the result.

To put it more clearly,
"WHERE" filter out the result set after finding the result from "**SELECT**" statement.
"AND" is a condition on joining the two tables.