# sql server, need to get total item qty for each item for each customer within date range

Tags: sql-server

I have 2 relational tables orders and order_items
orders has

- id
- customer_name
- delivery_date

order_items has

- order_id
- item
- unit
- qty

I need to see how much (ie. Sum(qty)) of each item/unit combination each customer ordered with in a specified date range.

the only way I see this can be done is to use C# or vb.net and first create a datatable with distinct item/unit combinations for the date range.
The I would loop through those item/units and get a total for a customer for them in that date range and add them to another datatable.

Is there a way to do this in sql alone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, there is:

```
SELECT customer_name, item, unit, SUM(Qty) as totals
FROM orders o INNER JOIN order_items oi 
  ON o.id = oi.order_id
WHERE o.delivery_date BETWEEN @datefrom AND @dateto
GROUP BY  customer_name, item, unit
ORDER BY  o.delivery_date
```

Comment: For performance, wouldn't it be better to put the date condition inside the `ON` and not inside the `WHERE`?

Comment: I doth think that this will make any difference in performance using `INNER JOIN`

Comment: @M.Massias: The query optimizer should resolve this correctly in either case.

Comment: Wasn't criticizing or suggesting an improvment, it's a genuine question for my personal knowledge :) because if the query execution planner does it right, then you could (theoretically) do a cross join, and put all of your conditions in a WHERE after that ?

Comment: @M.Massias have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10297231/where-clause-vs-on-when-using-join