# 'where' condition fails when left join returns null

Tags: php, mysql

When `left join` fails then due to `vlu.status=1` query does not return anything.
I want result even if left join fails.

If i remove `vlu.status=1` then it returns right result, but i have to use `vlu.status=1` when left join does not fails.

```
select vb.first_name,vb.last_name,DATE_FORMAT(vb.created_date,'%m-%d-%Y') as Created_On,
     concat(la.first_name,' ',la.last_name) as Loan_Agent, vl.loan_number, 
     count(vs.id) as Num_Deliveries from vid_borrowers vb 

         inner join vid_loans vl on vl.borrower_id= vb.id 
         left join vid_delivery_schedules vs on vs.borrower_id = vb.id
         left join vid_loan_agents la on la.id=vl.loan_officer_id 
         left join vid_users vlu on vlu.id=la.user_id 

     where vb.bank_id=6
       AND STR_TO_DATE(vb.created_date, '%Y-%m-%d') between  '2014-12-01' and '2014-12-16'
     and  vlu.status=1
     group by vb.first_name, vb.last_name, la.first_name, la.last_name, vl.loan_number
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the condition inside the join and remove it from the WHERE clause; doing so creates a NULL row if the condition fails *before* the WHERE gets involved.

```
 ...
 left join vid_users vlu on vlu.id=la.user_id and vlu.status = 1
 where vb.bank_id=6
   AND STR_TO_DATE(vb.created_date, '%Y-%m-%d') between  '2014-12-01' and '2014-12-16'
 group by vb.first_name, vb.last_name, la.first_name, la.last_name, vl.loan_number
```

You could let the WHERE take care of it as well by checking for NULL values, but IMHO it's better to perform the filter as soon as possible.

Comment: I didnt vote you down :O ... Thnx you solved my problem . i m checking for RIGHT tick but it says wait for 8 minutes

Comment: @ASP.NetDeveloper You do know that you can tick only one answer, right? You've been switching between two answers for a few minutes now :)

Comment: mr staurtLc has given answer earlier than you... i saw it later so thats why i ticked his answer... Your answer is also right

Comment: @ASP.NetDeveloper My answer was earlier; look at the timestamps, 05:53:19 (his) vs 05:52:53 (mine) .. in fact, that's what he mentioned earlier as well :)

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that by applying a `LEFT JOIN` and a `WHERE` filter is that the condition where the `LEFT JOIN` fails returns NULL for `vlu.status`, which is then filtered out in the `WHERE` (since the criteria is `vlu.status = 1`). You need to change either:

```
WHERE ...
AND (vlu.status = 1 OR vlu.status IS NULL) -- NULL for the Left Join
```

OR move the vlu.status filter into the LEFT JOIN criteria

```
LEFT JOIN vid_users vlu on vlu.id=la.user_id AND vlu.status = 1
```

[More on this here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10297231/where-clause-vs-on-when-using-join/10297312#10297312)

Answer (score 0):

The [`coalesce` function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce) takes a list of expressions and returns the first result that isn't null.  You can use it to replace nulls with a default value:

```
coalesce(vlu.status = 1, true)
```