# Sql Not IN Query using Join

Tags: sql, oracle

How can I write following query using left join here is my Sample Query

```
SELECT * 
FROM STUDENT st 
WHERE st.stdid not IN 
   (    SELECT csch.stid 
        FROM courseSchedule csch,    section sctn 
        WHERE cschno.sectno = sctn.sectno 
             AND cschno.college= sctn.college
             AND sctn.college = st.college AND sctn.year = 2013 and sctn.semester = 'spring' 
     )
     AND st.college = 1
```

Comment: Why don't you use EXISTS??

Comment: how can i use exisist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Waqas, I would use `EXISTS` for this (actually `NOT EXISTS`) as a commenter suggested above:

```
SELECT * FROM STUDENT st
 WHERE st.college = 1
   AND NOT EXISTS ( SELECT 1 FROM courseSchedule csch, section sctn
                     WHERE csch.stid = st.stdid
                       AND csch.sectno = sctn.sectno
                       AND csch.college = sctn.college
                       AND sctn.year = 2013
                       AND sctn.semester = 'spring'
                       AND sctn.college = st.college )
```

I notice you also have a typo in your query (the alias for `courseSchedule` is `csch`, not `cschno`).

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 5):

TO move the NOT IN subquery to a `LEFT JOIN`, do left join on the NOT IN key criteria, and instead, check for the Right table KEY as NULL. Note that you can also convert the `WHERE` join in the subquery to an ANSI join as well:

```
SELECT st.*
  FROM STUDENT st 
    LEFT JOIN courseSchedule csch 
      ON st.stdid = csch.stid 
    INNER JOIN section sctn 
      ON cschno.sectno = sctn.sectno 
     AND cschno.college= sctn.college
     AND sctn.college = st.college 
     AND sctn.year = 2013 
     AND sctn.semester = 'spring'
  WHERE st.college = 1
     AND csch.stid IS NULL; -- "Not IN"
```

Comment: i have little modified my query

Comment: You can handle additonal filter criteria in the same way. Note [there is a difference](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10297312/314291) between placing the criteria in the inner `LEFT JOIN` criteria, and in the outer `WHERE` clause which you need to be wary of.

Comment: can you guide me about that

Comment: I've added the additional criteria. Basically, unless ALL the criteria are met, the `RHS` table columns will be NULL because of the Left join, which is detected in the `WHERE` clause.