# Android SQLite LEFT JOIN - Date Filter is being ignored

Tags: android, sql, sqlite, select

I created a query that takes the data from 3 database tables.
In the table `Movimenti` I have a date field `yyyy-MM-dd`, with the where clause I want to get only the data of a given, instead I get the data from all the dates, where am I wrong?

```
String tabella_op = "SELECT m.id_operatore, " +
            "m.date, " +
            "m.ora_inizio, " +
            "m.minuti_inizio, " +
            "m.ora_fine, " +
            "m.minuti_fine, " +
            "m.id_servizio, " +
            "c._id, " +
            "c.nome, " +
            "c.cognome, " +
            "o.nome, " +
            "s.colore " +
            "FROM Movimenti m " +
            "LEFT JOIN Clienti c ON (m.id_cliente = c._id) " +
            "LEFT JOIN Servizi s ON (m.id_servizio = s._id) " +
            "LEFT JOIN Operatori o ON (o._id = m.id_operatore) " +
            "AND m.date = 2015-04-23 ORDER BY m.id_operatore ASC";
```

Comment: That doesn't appear to be correct syntax. Where is `WHERE`? I'm surprised it even executes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to move the filter on the primary `LEFT` Table (`Movimenti`) out of the `JOIN` condition, back into a `WHERE` clause:

```
String tabella_op = "SELECT m.id_operatore, " +
        "m.date, " +
        "m.ora_inizio, " +
        "m.minuti_inizio, " +
        "m.ora_fine, " +
        "m.minuti_fine, " +
        "m.id_servizio, " +
        "c._id, " +
        "c.nome, " +
        "c.cognome, " +
        "o.nome, " +
        "s.colore " +
        "FROM Movimenti m " +
        "LEFT JOIN Clienti c ON (m.id_cliente = c._id) " +
        "LEFT JOIN Servizi s ON (m.id_servizio = s._id) " +
        "LEFT JOIN Operatori o ON (o._id = m.id_operatore) " +
        "WHERE m.date = 2015-04-23 ORDER BY m.id_operatore ASC";
```

More on WHY this works like [this here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10297312/314291), but the *TL;DR* is that if any of the `LEFT JOINs` fail, then the filter on `m.Date` will be ignored altogether.