# Use of parenthesis in Sql Join statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I would like to know what is the difference between

```
INNER JOIN TB_PACKAGE AS B
    ON (A.CdPackage = B.CdPackage)
```

and

```
INNER JOIN TB_PACKAGE AS B
    ON A.CdPackage = B.CdPackage
```

When I should use the parenthesis and when not, I need some sort of explanation.

Here is the entire query, it is a stored procedure:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [DB].[SP_UP_NOTES]
  @COD_ROTE  NUMERIC(10)
 ,@COD_STATS   NUMERIC(10)
AS

BEGIN

  UPDATE C
  SET C.IdStatus = @COD_STATS
  FROM DB.TB_NOTES AS A
  INNER JOIN OPMDM.TB_PACKAGE AS B
    ON (A.CdPackage= B.CdPackage)
  INNER JOIN OPMDM.TB_NOTES AS C
    ON (A.CdNotes = c.CdNotes)
  WHERE B.STATS = @COD_ROTE;

END
```

Comment: Unless the JOIN condition has a mix of logical operators, e.g. `a.X = b.X AND (a.Y = b.Y OR a.Foo = 'Bar')` you won't need parenthesis. Some however use parenthesis for readability, but this is a subjective preference.

Comment: Thank's for the explanation, really helpfull !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Your Above Code, there is no difference between the Code with and Without parenthesis. But In some cases, Use of parenthesis can make a diffrece

For Example If you are using AND and OR operators combined

```
SELECT
*
FROM YourTable
WHERE 
(
id > 10 and Name Like 'A%'
)
or
(
Id < 10 and name Like '%A'
)
```

In the above case Use of parenthesis Makes some effect since I want to get the records that Match the Criteria `id > 10 and Name Like 'A%'` or `Id < 10 and name Like '%A'`

here I want to group the 2 AND conditions and Generate the List of records that satisfy either of the conditions, So I am using parenthesis

Comment: In your example, `AND` has precedence over `OR` anyway, so the parenthesis are still unnecessary. Also, be careful - Applying a filter in `OUTER JOINs` is [NOT the same](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10297312/314291) as applying a filter in a `WHERE` clause.

Answer (score 2):

No difference at all. The only time you need parentheses is if you need to do a complex join that requires enforcing of AND/OR evaluation order.